# Calculating difference between two years in excel with if else condition

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, difference

I want to calculate difference of second date (year) and first date(year). 
I cannot write formula in excel.

```
if(quitDate is not empty)
{
  quitDate - startDate
}
else 
{
  presentDate - startDate
}
```

I know only these two formulas =YEAR(NOW)-YEAR(A1) 
and = YEAR(B1)-YEAR(A1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
=IF(quitDate<>"",quitDate-startDate,NOW()-startDate)
```

where I have used Named Ranges (each one cell) for the two dates. I imagine you would prefer to replace those with suitable `A1` references to make copying easier.